# Trying to get a change event to fire only when multiple text inputs have changed

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

I have two text input fields (that are actually the inputs for jQuery UI datepickers) and one select field. The code is:

```
<input type="text" id="datepickerStart" name="datepickerStart" placeholder="Start hire"/>
<input type="text" id="datepickerEnd" name="datePickerEnd" placeholder="End hire"/>
<select name="hireQuantity" id="hireQuantity">
```

I am trying to change the background colour of the select, only when BOTH text inputs have fired their change events. Every solution I try tends to change when either input is changed. I've tried conditional statements, `.add()`, but I am out of ideas. Here's my most basic code attempt, any suggestions?

`$('#datepickerStart', '#datepickerEnd').change(function() {                      $('#hireQuantity').css('background','rgb(249,237,50)'); });//end change`

Answer (score 3):

Add a class on change (or use data() or whatever) and just check if both elements have that class, if they do the selector would have a length of 2, just make sure no other elements in the DOM but the two datepickers accidently have that same class

```
$('#datepickerStart', '#datepickerEnd').change(function() {
    $(this).addClass('changed');

    if ($('.changed').length == 2)
        $('#hireQuantity').css('background','rgb(249,237,50)');
});
```

Comment: Yes.  There are lots of ways to do it, really, but the key point is that you need to keep track of the state -- has one changed or have both changed, given that they won't change at the same time.  You could store the state in a variable, or in a data attribute, or, as suggested, by adding a class.

Comment: @JacobM - Indeed, I came up with numerous ways just by looking at the question, and there's probably many I haven't thought of as well, but just using a class seemed like the easiest to explain in a short piece of code.

Comment: Thanks guys for getting back to me so quickly, I really appreciate it, I've tried changing the class option, on standard text input, it would work brilliantly, but jQuery UI datepicker  overrides with it's own class irrespective of the change event '.hasDatepicker', even chaining with .removeClass() doesn't set it up for the .addClass(). I'll try setting data attribute route or holding the state in a variable.. will let you know how it goes :) thanks again

Comment: Hi guys, to give you an update, I got it to work. I opted for data attribute setting as I didn't want to mess with that class that was inherent with the UI date pickers. Having said that, it refused to work for ages, until i captured $(this) as a variable before setting the attribute..! Once again, thanks guys I really appreciate the support for a new jQuery kid like myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/h9H7w/) that handles this in a slightly different way.

Html:

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepickerStart" name="datepickerStart" placeholder="Start hire" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepickerEnd" name="datePickerEnd" placeholder="End hire" />
<select name="hireQuantity" id="hireQuantity"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function clickHandler (count, cb) {
    var changed;
    changed = [];
    return function (e) {
        if (-1 === changed.indexOf(e.currentTarget)) {
            changed.push(e.currentTarget);
            if (0 < count) {
                cb.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
$('.datepicker').change(clickHandler(0, function () {
    $('#hireQuantity').css('background','rgb(249,237,50)');
}));
```

Comment: Now try changing the first input twice, and see how your code has some serious flaws ?

Comment: @adeneo Just updated again to make it a bit clearer what I like about my approach. This clickHandler (a better name might be good), is a bit more reusable, because we can get the same functionality for as many elements on the page as we'd like.